# Unicode @font-face text working in FF, not in Chrome and IE

Tags: c#, css, internet-explorer, encoding, font-face

I'm having problems getting @font-face working using Asian text, it shows boxes instead of some of the characters. It works fine in FF though (bottom image), but not in IE 8 and Chrome (top image) . The page is UTF-8. What could be going on here ? I'm not sure if it's an issue with the font, my code or the browser. Some other fonts work OK, so I could change, but if it's a font problem or missing glyphs why would it still work in Firefox ?

[image]

The CSS is basically straight from the FontSquirrel generator.

```
@font-face {   font-family: 'fontname';src: url('/fonts/fontname-webfont.eot');  
               src: url('/fonts/fontname-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
               url('/fonts/fontname-webfont.woff') format('woff'); }
.fontname {font-family: 'fontname', Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was just an encoding issue with that specific font.